# How to get the coordinates of the stitched image with respect to the original images

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I am performing object detection on multiple images, captured from multiple cameras covering a wider angle of view. As I would like to prevent counting the same object multiple times, I am wondering if it is possible to calculate the coordinates of the object on the stitched image with respect to the coordinates of the source images. This way, if coordinates of multiple object on the source images would be approximately equal on the stitched image, I would count the object only once. Below is the example image stitching: the stitched image is composed of 3 overlapping images; on the first and second image, the same object is detected and should be counted only once.

[image]

This is an example code I wrote for stitching:

```
import cv2
import imutils
from videostream import VideoStreamWidget

index = 0
arr = []

stitcher = cv2.createStitcher() if imutils.is_cv3() else cv2.Stitcher_create()


cams_test = 200
for i in range(cams_test):
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(i)
    test, frame = cap.read()
    if test:
        print("i : " + str(i) + " /// result: " + str(test))
        arr.append(i)

video_captures = [VideoStreamWidget(idx) for idx in arr]
images_to_stitch = []
for i, video_stream_widget in enumerate(video_captures):
    try:
        if video_stream_widget.frame is not None:
            cv2.imshow('Cam {}'.format(i), cv2.resize(video_stream_widget.frame, (0, 0), fx=0.25, fy=0.25))
            images_to_stitch.append(video_stream_widget.frame)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        pass
try:
    (status, stitched) = stitcher.stitch(images_to_stitch)
    if status == 0:
        cv2.imshow("Stitched", cv2.resize(stitched, (0, 0), fx=0.1, fy=0.25))
except:
    print("stitching failed")
print(status)
```

Comment: how it is stiched? can you add some minimum reproducible code here ?

Comment: You may start with [`cv2.match_template()`](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/dc6/tutorial_py_template_matching.html)

Answer (score 0):

Can we assume that your stitching is not dynamic in any way, and that you always take a fixed part of the initial images to create the main one?

In that case, I would store the center coordinates of your objects and check (after the stitching) if two centers are within a certain tolerance. (So you initially tolerate the redundancy and remove it after the stitching). e.g. x,y +/- 20 pixels.